# ERROR: HDL COMPILER:806 Line 31: Syntax error near "sumador"

Tags: verilog

I don't know why every time I compile I get this error. Please I need your help. Thanks

```
module operaciones(

    input [3:0] A,
    input [3:0] B,
    input [3:0] numop,
    output reg [3:0] C
    );

  wire bas1,bas2;

  always  @ ( A[3] | A[2] | A[1] | A[0] | B[3] | B[2] | B[1] | B[0] | numop[3] | numop[2] | numop[1] | numop[0] )

    case (numop)
      4'b0000 : sumador_4bits sumador(A,B,bas1,C,bas2);
      4'b0001 : restador_4bits restador(A,B,C);
      4'b0010 : mult_4bits multiplicador(A,B,C);
      4'b0011 : complemento_a_1 comp1(A,C);
      4'b0100 : complemento_a_2 comp2(A,C);
      4'b0101 : AND anda(A,B,C);
      4'b0110 : OR ora(A,B,C);
      4'b0111 : NOT nota(A,C);
      4'b1000 : XOR xora(A,B,C);
    endcase

endmodule
```

Comment: You can't create submodules instances in `case` construct like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate a module inside of an always block.  If the operation to be performed is determined at execution time, then you need to instantiate all of these instances outside of the always block and then determine which one you use to assign the output with the case statement like this:

```
module operaciones(

    input [3:0] A,
    input [3:0] B,
    input [3:0] numop,
    output reg [3:0] C
    );

  wire bas1,bas2;

  wire [3:0] C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8;

  sumador_4bits sumador(A,B,bas1,C0,bas2);
  restador_4bits restador(A,B,C1);
  mult_4bits multiplicador(A,B,C2);
  complemento_a_1 comp1(A,C3);
  complemento_a_2 comp2(A,C4);
  and1 anda(A,B,C5);
  or1 ora(A,B,C6);
  not1 nota(A,C7);
  xor1 xora(A,B,C8);

  always  @ ( C0 or C1 or C2 or C3 or C4 or C5 or C6 or C7 or C8 or numop )
    case (numop)
      4'b0000 : C = C0;
      4'b0001 : C = C1;
      4'b0010 : C = C2;
      4'b0011 : C = C3;
      4'b0100 : C = C4;
      4'b0101 : C = C5;
      4'b0110 : C = C6;
      4'b0111 : C = C7;
      4'b1000 : C = C8;
      default : C = C0;
    endcase
endmodule
```

The other changes that I made:

- The sensitivity list should use `or` instead of `|`
- You don't need to list every bit of a vector in a sensitivity list, just list the vector
- It looks like you are using your own modules for the built-in gates (and, or, ...) but you are using instance names that are just different from these reserved words based on capitalization. I changed the instance names, so that it isn't just capitalization that makes them legal names.
- I don't know if you want to synthesize this, but if you did, then this would have synthesized in a latch since the case statement wasn't complete.  I've added in a default so that there is an assignment no matter what the inputs are.